# iOS and Erlang - SSL Handshake failed with self signed certificates

Tags: ios, ssl, erlang, handshake

I am trying to create a SSL connection over TCP/IP from iOS to an Erlang server. The server is using self-signed certificates (default certificates shipped with Erlang OTP).

Every time, the SSL Handshake fails:
- CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824 -> -9829)
- CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)

This is one method I use:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"my-server-name", 1234, &readStream, &writeStream);

//------------------------------------------------------
// Set props.
//
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain, kCFBooleanFalse);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamSSLPeerName, kCFNull);

CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain, kCFBooleanFalse);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamSSLPeerName, kCFNull);

//------------------------------------------------------
// Open streams.
//
if(!CFReadStreamOpen(readStream))
{
    NSLog(@"CFReadStreamOpen Failed!");
    return 0;
}

if(!CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream))
{
    NSLog(@"CFWriteStreamOpen Failed!");
    CFReadStreamClose(readStream);
    return 0;
}

//------------------------------------------------------
// Send some data.
//
UInt8 data[20] = {0};

*(ushort*)data = 18;
for(int i = 2; i < 20; i++)
{
    data[i] = 'A' + i;
}

NSLog(@"Sending some data...");

CFIndex bytesSent = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, data, 20);
NSLog(@"Bytes Sent: %d", (int)bytesSent);

//------------------------------------------------------
// Close streams.
//
CFReadStreamClose(readStream);
CFWriteStreamClose(writeStream);
```

I tried also with SecureTransport ( SSLCreateContext, SSLSetConnection, SSLHandshake  and it is the same - SSL handshake fails.

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons for the error. You should probably begin by using the `curl` command on your Mac to access the Erlang server. Curl will give you more descriptive errors. You'll need to pass the `-k` flag to tell it to ignore cert errors.

Some quick possibilities: Is your Objective-C code set to allow invalid certs? Is it set to validate the domain name, and your development setup doesn't do reverse DNS?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is related to AppTransport you can find which exception you need by running `/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose yourdomain.com` on MacOS 10.11.